# What happens after host receives physical data from router

Tags: networking, network-programming

I know that when two machine communicate they may use the TCP/IP protocol.. But after the IP packet is routed to my router and it is converted to physical signal , how does my computer again decapsulate it and send it to proper application....I know that transport layer header is used for identifying port numbers to send it to proper process,but which device will do all these inside a host..am new to network and apologize if something was wrong or silly here

Comment: That would be handled by a network adapter (NIC) in the host, it could be an ethernet adapter or something else.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez and am always confused with networks bcoz all textbooks gives info layer by layer and Iam not getting the big picture ie layers working together... How to know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **packet** comprises of information in the form of **[header[body]]** which will be looked up and processed across all the layers in the TCP/IP stack.

The information related to the all layers are encapsulated into a single packet. 
Packet being a general term here, can be of many types based on the protocol with which two nodes are communicating (TCP Packet, UDP Packet, IP Packet etc). The information from a TCP/IP packet for example, are processed by different **devices or services** working at specific layers.

- Switches or Bridges operate at the Ethernet layer. These devices switch packets inside LAN by looking up the MAC address information.
- Routers operate at the Internet Layer and utilizes the IP protocol (i.e., IP address) to route traffic between networks.
- Stateful firewalls, Proxies, Load Balancers etc. are at the transport layer. They work based on the TCP or UDP information to allow/deny/direct traffic.
- Application layer facilities effective communication between application programs in a network. The application layer is not the application itself that is doing the communication. It has protocols such as DNS, FTP, SMTP, SNMP to help and serve the purpose.

References: 
https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking/firewall/ch06_03.htm
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc786128(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: ,well the explanation is good,but my question was a bit different....and btw Mac address is used even outside the LAN or even when routers communicate right?....ie when router consults it's routing table to know the next router ,it sends to next router only after knowing the Mac address of that router

Comment: @akshay I believe I have answered your queries, "which device will do all these inside a host" & "I am not getting the big picture ie layers working together... How to know that...".

Perhaps, you can use tools like "Wireshark" to analyse the packets and get the big picture.

MAC addresses are unique identifiers which are assigned to NICs. And are used at the Ethernet Layer by the Switches not Routers. MAC addresses aren't much useful outside the LAN.

Comment: oh Sry u answered to my question in comments section.thanks a lot.but actually the routers do use the MAC address to send packet at layer 3 to another router ...was that ryt

Comment: No they do not.